# AuthorizeAttribute AuthorizeCore return False

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I spent 2 days trying to research solution to my problem without any success. I hope that somebody here can point me in the right direction.

I have one app divided into 3 separate solutions.

One app is login center where users can login using FormsAuthentication.
Second two are separate modules that are not important here. Recently I was asked to add 4th application to login center. App is very old and I have problems adding it to login center.

4 app web config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login center url" timeout="2880" name="cookie name" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

4 app AuthorizeAttribute :

```
  public class AppAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute  
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool result = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        return result;  // here i always have false
    }
}
```

So when i try to login into my 4th app I get redirected to login app get successful login and return back but my AuthorizeCore always return false. 
Modules are hosted on IIS under one web page in different virtual directories.

What could be the issue here ? I really don't know and will share more details if needed. I also will add that this solution works for 2 other apps don't know reason why this isn't working on this one.

Comment: What does the base AuthorizeCore constructor do?

Comment: Have you checked if the authentication cookie is present in the request?

Comment: Do you have machine keys set in the 4th app? These should match the login center.

Comment: This article might also help you: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for response. This post directed me to the my answer  [Sharing a cookie between two websites on the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927941/sharing-a-cookie-between-two-websites-on-the-same-domain) 4 app was originaly written in .Net 4 and when i incresed version to 4.5 this `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />`  wasn't added to web config. I don't know why.