# Sharing authentication cookie between DNN Site and ASP.NET Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication, dotnetnuke

I have a DNN site on `example.com` and an MVC site on `subdomain.example.com`. I've set up `MembershipProvider` and a `RoleProvider` in according to this article: [SharePoint-Forms-Based-Authentication-Using-DotNet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28525/SharePoint-Forms-Based-Authentication-Using-DotNet). Now I want to share auth cookie between two sites. I've set up domain keys in both `web.config` files like `domain=".example.com"`. Fiddler says the same cookie is used when requesting to any of the sites. And there's a following effect: When I log in to one of the sites, I'm being logged off from another. What could I missed?

Below is a part of the `web.config` of the MVC site:

```xml
<machineKey
  validationKey="DEE8F9D31F46D663FA0BCF9A6A9701B0796777C5"
  decryptionKey="E75FBCF55F6BB0B2A352036B965725FD739B2EB21B790659"
  decryption="3DES"
  validation="SHA1" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms 
    name=".DOTNETNUKE"
    protection="All" 
    timeout="60" 
    cookieless="UseCookies" 
    loginUrl="~/Account/Login" 
    domain=".example.com" 
    path="/" />
</authentication>
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" domain=".example.com" />
<!-- Configure the Sql Membership Provider -->
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add
      name="SqlMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="DnnSqlServer"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false"
      passwordFormat="Hashed"
      applicationName="DotNetNuke" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<!-- Configure the Sql Role Provider -->
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add
      name="SqlRoleProvider"
      connectionStringName="DnnSqlServer"
      applicationName="DotNetNuke"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider,System.Web,
            Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,
            PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Finally I've found a solution on stackoverflow pages: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21087932/4703971](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21087932/4703971)

Answer (score 0):

When you see this behavior it is typically from the encryption MachineKey values being different between the different applications.  When the other application attempts to read the cookie, it cannot decrypt it and then deletes it, allowing you to login.

I would validate those items in the web.config.  (They are not too far down from the  node.

Comment: Yes, I've already checked this out, because when the machine keys were not the same, an error 'The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted' was occured.I've updated my web.config in the answer.